# How do i make the input to show infobox even when i click on the show button without glitching

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a code where I am showing a infobox when user clicks on an input field. This works fine but to make the UX better I would like the infobox to remain open when user clicks on a show button. It shouldn't close and open again

```
  <div class="text-field">
   <input type="text" class="username" name="username" placeholder="username" />
    <button class="show-pwd">show</button>
  </div>
  <div class="info" style="display: none;">
    <p>hello world</p>
  </div>
```

```
$(function() {
  
  const username = $('.username');
  const showPwd = $('.show-pwd');
  showPwd.click(()=>{
    username.get(0).type = 'password';
    $('.info').show();
  });
  $('.username').on("focus",(e)=>{
        $('.info').show();
    });
  $('.username').on("blur",(e)=>{
        $('.info').hide();
    });
});
```

```
.text-field input {
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.text-field {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 200px;
  height: 25px;
}

.info {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
}
```

[heres the codepen](https://codepen.io/bahag-hamidk/pen/XWPJdGQ?editors=1111)

I tried to add the show method in click handler but that just adds a glitch

Comment: is it the right codepen?

Comment: thanks @FabrizioCalderan just updated the link it was wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The blinking is happening because input blurring is triggered first, and then the button click.

You can avoid the blinking with a slight delay when blurring / moving out of the input, like in the following example.

```js
const username = $('.username');
const showPwd = $('.show-pwd');
var btnClicked = false; // this is new

showPwd.click(()=>{
  btnClicked = true; // this is new
  username.get(0).type = 'password';
  $('.info').show();
});

$('.username').on("focus",(e)=>{
  $('.info').show();
});

$('.username').on("blur",(e)=>{
  setTimeout(function() {
    if(!btnClicked) {
      $('.info').hide();
    }
  },100);
});
```

```css
.text-field input {
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.text-field {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 200px;
  height: 25px;
}

.info {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text-field">
  <input type="text" class="username" name="username" placeholder="username" />
  <button class="show-pwd">show</button>
</div>
<div class="info" style="display: none;">
  <p>hello world</p>
</div>
```

One suggestion - since the current setup (and the original one) have no way of hiding the `.info` div once the button has been clicked, consider making your `.show-pwd` button a toggle button - one click to show the info div (if it's not visible), and another to hide it (if it's visible).

If you decide to do that, you would have to change my initial suggestion a bit, in order to avoid hiding the info div when moving from your input to your button.

And if you're up for some UX suggestions, you could change the show button - for example, you could use the open / closed eye icon to reflect what would happen on button click (similar to show / hide password in various online services, like Gmail, and the like).